# Problema multi auth LARAVEL 5.8

Tags: laravel, autenticación

les explico, tengo 3 tablas en mi bd, las cuales son admin, alumno y profesor, lo que necesito es que al logearme me revise las 3 tablas para ver si existe ese usuario con su contraseña, he leído mucho de laravel multi auth y probado múltiples formas pero ninguna me resulta, si alguien sabe en que se debe mi error, o alguna forma y que les hubiera resultado, me enviarían la documentación o vídeo que siguieron por favor, gracias.
Adjunto código

**auth.php**

```js
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'alumno' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'alumnos',
        ],

        'alumno-api' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'alumnos',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'profesor' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'profesors',
        ],

        'profesor-api' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'profesors',
            'hash' => false,
        ]
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'alumnos'  => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Alumno::class,
        ],

        'profesors'  => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Profesor::class,
        ]

    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'alumnos' => [
            'provider' => 'alumnos',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'profesors' => [
            'provider' => 'profesors',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

**Alumno Model (la tabla de profesor tienen lo mismo campos, solo que en otra tabla, para no agregar tanto código lo hago así)**

```js
class Alumno extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'alumno';
    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'id_alumno',
        'rut',
        'nombre',
        'apellidos',
        'correo',
        'telefono',
        'clave'
    ];
    
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**Alumno Controller (el Controller profesor tienen lo mismo campos, solo que en otro controllador [profesorController], coloque alumno nomas para no agregar tanto código)**

```js
class alumnoController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('alumno');
    }
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php**

```js
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

**/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero su ayuda, muchas gracias!

Comment: es que uso el comando php artisan make:auth

Comment: aaa perdon estoy ocupando laravel 5.8 amigo :c

Comment: ok, entonces, muéstranos que tienes en los archivos `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` y `/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`

Comment: Ya amigo, dame un rato, gracias por responder, con mi amigo te tenemos en un altar jajaja

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ya agregue lo que me solicitaste amigo

Comment: Hola amigo, te invito a que veas este post detalladamente que explica muy bien acerca de este tema : https://medium.com/@sagarmaheshwary31/laravel-multiple-guards-authentication-setup-and-login-2761564da986 , todo converge en los "guards" al momento de autenticar el el controlador, haces una serie de if donde validas cada Auth::guard() de cada tabla que vas a validar, tendrías que ver el post para que entiendas mejor.

Comment: Resolviste esto? Le dí una mirada al tutorial que te pasó Abdiel y parece ser justo lo que estás buscando

Comment: si de echo lo estaba viendo, y encontre incluso un video en otro idio lo trate de seguir pero no me funciono :c @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: lo hare de nuevo a ver si me resulta :c